# Errors appearing when using Rs summarize function. Any idea what could be causing this?

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a very large set of data with this structure:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(19034, 19034, 19034, 19034, 19034, 19034, 19034, 19034, 19034, 19034), 
                                  class = "Date"),type = c("O/N", "O/N", "T/C", "FB", "T/C", "T/C", "FB", "FB", "O/N", "O/N"), 
                 time = structure(c(28796, 32403, 36003, 43203, 46803, 50404, 50408, 54011, 54014, 58815), units = "secs", class = c("hms", "difftime")), 
                 quantity = c(0.003, 0.007, 0.002, 0.001, 0.03, 0.123, 0.017, 0.019, 0.012, 0.01 ),cumvol = c(0.003, 0.01, 0.012, 0.013, 0.043, 0.166, 0.183, 0.202, 0.214, 0.224)), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I'm trying to create a table that will summarize quantity data by type and by day at some specific timestamps as well as providing with me with total data for the day:

```
time_check <- c(13, 16, 18)

summaryt <- df %>% 
     mutate(time_hr = hour(time), .after = time) %>% 
     filter(time_hr %in% time_check) %>% 
     group_by(date, type, time_hr) %>% 
     summarize(cat_total = sum(quantity)) %>% 
     group_by(date) %>% 
     mutate(date_total = sum(cat_total)) %>% 
     ungroup()
```

Weirdly using the above code (and abbreviated dataset posted here) works fine on a 'fresh' opening of R. However applying it to the main dataset (which constitutes millions of obs) it throws up two errors intermittently:

```
Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.
* Column `TradeDate` is not found.
```

This seems to be caused by the line:

```
summarize(cat_total = sum(quantity))
```

Which seems to drop most of the columns, including the date (which is required for the group_by(date) line) leaving only the cat_total.

Very occasionally, I've run the code (without changing anything) and got this error:

```
   Error in [[<-.data.frame(*tmp*, col, value = 13L) :
replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

Which is very strange given the intermittency of this error.

Here's the session info:

```
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

attached base packages:
[1] compiler  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.5.1          purrr_0.3.4            readr_2.1.1            tibble_3.1.6           tidyverse_1.3.1        plyr_1.8.6             ggrepel_0.9.1         
 [8] hms_1.1.1              stringi_1.7.6          zoo_1.8-9              TTR_0.24.3             cowplot_1.1.1          kableExtra_1.3.4       knitr_1.37            
[15] matrixStats_0.61.0     magick_2.7.3           gridExtra_2.3          ggthemes_4.2.4         directlabels_2021.1.13 bizdays_1.0.8          extrafont_0.17        
[22]        lubridate_1.8.0        ggplot2_3.3.5          readxl_1.3.1           data.table_1.14.2      stringr_1.4.0          dplyr_1.0.7           
[29] tidyr_1.1.4            rmarkdown_2.11         feather_0.3.5          RDCOMClient_0.94-0    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.2        jsonlite_1.7.3    viridisLite_0.4.0 modelr_0.1.8      assertthat_0.2.1  cellranger_1.1.0  yaml_2.2.1        Rttf2pt1_1.3.9    pillar_1.6.4     
[10] backports_1.4.1   lattice_0.20-45   glue_1.6.1        quadprog_1.5-8    extrafontdb_1.0   digest_0.6.29     rvest_1.0.2       colorspace_2.0-2  htmltools_0.5.2  
[19] pkgconfig_2.0.3   broom_0.7.11      haven_2.4.3       scales_1.1.1      webshot_0.5.2     svglite_2.0.0     tzdb_0.2.0        farver_2.1.0      generics_0.1.1   
[28] ellipsis_0.3.2    withr_2.4.3       lazyeval_0.2.2    cli_3.1.1         magrittr_2.0.1    crayon_1.4.2      evaluate_0.14     fs_1.5.2          fansi_1.0.2      
[37] xts_0.12.1        xml2_1.3.3        tools_4.0.5       lifecycle_1.0.1   plotly_4.10.0     reprex_2.0.1      munsell_0.5.0     systemfonts_1.0.3 rlang_0.4.12     
[46] grid_4.0.5        rstudioapi_0.13   htmlwidgets_1.5.4 crosstalk_1.2.0   labeling_0.4.2    gtable_0.3.0      DBI_1.1.2         curl_4.3.2        R6_2.5.1         
[55] fastmap_1.1.0     utf8_1.2.2        Rcpp_1.0.8        vctrs_0.3.8       dbplyr_2.1.1      tidyselect_1.1.1  xfun_0.29
```

Comment: Try `dplyr::summarize`, probably `plyr::summarize` is used.

Comment: Ahh wonderful det, that worked a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WIth thanks to det, I was able to fix by changing:

```
summarize(cat_total = sum(quantity))
```

To:

```
dplyr::summarize(cat_total = sum(quantity))
```